# ImageMagick Multiply two images (add color)

Tags: imagemagick, multiplication

I can't find command for ImageMagick which do effect likes on images below (dont worry, these funny imgs are for example only:-) ).
I tried many solutions but the problem is that any elements on gradient disappear after add color to it.
I can't find solution for this, because after any blend, or colorizing all shaded details on source image dissapear.

Example below is not ideal, I made this in GIMP. But in ImageShack results are worse... (I dont show them:D )

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't show what you are aiming for, but it looks good to me using the `blend` option:

```
convert -size 200x187 xc:red red.png
convert http://i.imgur.com/P2s0cKQ.png red.png -compose blend -composite out.png
```

[image]

Or, you can do it all in one go, like this:

```
convert http://i.imgur.com/P2s0cKQ.png              \
   \( +clone -evaluate set 0 -channel R -negate \)  \
   -compose blend -composite out.png
```

This clones the original image, then sets all three channels (RG&B) to zero and the inverts the Red channel to set it to full red.

Other possible blending modes can be found using

```
identify -list compose
```

and they will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow... I can't imagine better answer. Thanks :-)